# База данных интернет магазина

Tags: mysql

Нужно создать базу данных для интернет магазина, но есть одна загвоздка, к примеру один товар может продаваться по упаковкам (Рис.1), а другой поштучно(Рис.2). Как можно реализовать это в базе данных?
[image: Рис.1]
[image: Рис.2]

Comment: Таблицей, в которой будут перечисляться все виды продажи продукта?

Comment: Просто считаем, что одна упаковка является одной штукой. Так делают все магазины - сходите купите любую упаковку и почитайте что в чеке будет написано